# Keycloak docker authentication

Tags: node.js, express, docker, keycloak

I am trying to build node.js server with Express, MongoDB and Keycloak.
At the same time I need to use Docker for this. So, I've put node express server, mongodb and keycloak in different containers. When I run docker compose, I have functioning containers. My app is communicating with database. The problem is that routes that are protected with keycloak are reporting that the Access is denied. I know that there is a similar question  here on stackoverflow, but it was left without answer. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that keycloak.json that was given to me by dockerized keycloak server had   "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:5000/auth" in it.

This meant that my dockerized node server was trying to authenticate my routes by referring to itself. What should be done here is to put IPv4 address of your machine instead of localhost and dockerized Keycloak server will grant you access.